# iOS: Portrait & Landsacpe without adjusting programatically

Tags: ios, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

- Am creating an screen that supports both `landscape` & `portrait`
- While am changing the `orientation` it miss match the `design`
- Is there any way to adjust the screen `without adding any code` to adjust.
- Because am using an dynamic project.

**Screenshot**: This is the way am set orientation for whole app in plist

[image]

Any solution please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use auto layout (iOS7-above only), if <iOS7 you should do by code

Answer (score 1):

You should use Auto Layout feature (from iOS 6.0).

Take a look at:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto Layout if you support iOS 6 and later, or you could simply use the Autoresizing Masks for earlier versions.

Auto Layout allows you to do complex layouts for most scenarios, but in some cases you'll still need to programatically adjust the constraints.

Check this out for more information on how to get started: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html